# What / How does the Unified Configuration Interface in OpenWRT convert the contents of the files in /etc/config/* files?

Tags: linux, openwrt, uci

UCI is a cli program that allows you to edit files in `/etc/config/` without opening them up; it makes editing OpenWRT configs almost like editing the DOM...however; I am unaware what reads these configuration files and turns them into either other configuration files or bash commands and arguments.

What abstraction does this?

Comment: Bash is most definitely not involved, because it is not installed by default on OpenWrt. // https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/uci

Comment: @DanielB Is that better?  I updated it to BusyBox;  But I have compiled it and run it on Bash in Ubuntu.

Comment: It’s not really about better or not. It’s just a regular CLI program. It’s not tied to either Busybox or Bash or whatever.

Comment: @DanielB okay....it's fixed.

Comment: @fixer1234 `unified-configuration-interface` is more than 25 characters so I can't use it.

Comment: @leeand00, it isn't clear exactly what you're looking for in an answer.  UCI is a collection of scripts designed to directly modify the configuration files.  What aspects of that process are you looking to be expanded in more detail that's still within Super User's scope?  It seems like getting into the nitty gritty of how command line scripts modify files would probably be off-topic here.

Comment: @fixer1234 That's precisely what I wanted to know...what modifies the files with UCI.   I didn't know it was a collection of scripts; do you know where the scripts are located so I can take a look at them?

Comment: Looks like that's covered in the technical reference here: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/uci#usage_outside_of_openwrt